# How to process a subquery returning more than 1 row in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i process the query I've tried multiple ways and it does not work. I'm trying to show only the CentreCode that have more than 3 combinations with ShopNo

```
SELECT CentreCode, ShopNo
FROM shoppingcentreshop
WHERE (SELECT count(*) as total FROM shoppingcentreshop GROUP BY CentreCode) > 2
```

```
SELECT CentreCode, ShopNo, (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM shoppingcentreshop GROUP BY CentreCode) AS table1
FROM shoppingcentreshop
WHERE table1.total > 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause without `group by`:

```
SELECT s.CentreCode, s.ShopNo
FROM shoppingcentreshop s
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shoppingcentreshop WHERE CentreCode = s.CentreCode) > 2
```